# difference between cgroups and namespaces

Tags: linux, docker, cgroups

I recently started learning docker and it seems that most of the heavy lifting is done by the Linux kernel, using namespaces and cgroups.

A few things which I am finding confusing are:

1. What is the difference between a namespace and a cgroup? What are the different use cases they address?
2. What has docker implemented on top this these to gain popularity ?
3. I would like to know the internals of these features and how they are implemented.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups#Namespace_isolation

Comment: "A cgroup is a collection of processes that are bound to a set of limits or parameters defined via the cgroup filesystem." see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The proper links for those two notions have been fixed in [PR 14307](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14307/files):

> Under the hood, Docker is built on the following components:
>
> The **[cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt)** and [`namespaces`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) capabilities of the Linux kernel

With:

- **cgroup**: Control Groups provide a mechanism for aggregating/partitioning sets of tasks, and all their future children, into hierarchical groups with specialized behaviour.
- **namespace**: wraps a global system resource in an abstraction that makes it appear to the processes within the namespace that they have their own isolated instance of the global resource.

In short:

- **Cgroups** = limits how much you can use;
- **namespaces** = limits what you can see (and therefore use)

See more at "[Anatomy of a Container: Namespaces, cgroups & Some Filesystem Magic](http://fr.slideshare.net/jpetazzo/anatomy-of-a-container-namespaces-cgroups-some-filesystem-magic-linuxcon)" by [Jérôme Petazzoni](http://fr.slideshare.net/jpetazzo).

Cgroups involve resource metering and limiting:

- memory
- CPU
- block I/O
- network

Namespaces  provide processes with their own view of the system

Multiple namespaces:

- pid
- net
- mnt
- uts
- ipc
- user: **userns** it is [graduating from experimental in docker 1.10](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19187)
  (per-daemon-instance remapping of container root to an unprivileged user is in progress: [PR 12648](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/12648): see its [design](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/11253))

Comment: Thanks. Is `chroot` based on some namespace? Can `chroot` be replaced by some namespace?

Comment: No, chroot is not based on a namespace: see https://itnext.io/chroot-cgroups-and-namespaces-an-overview-37124d995e3d. More than three years later though, keep in mind the new Docker (19.03, still in beta) can be run as rootless: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/c12f09bf99b54f274a5ae241dd154fa74020cbab/contrib/dockerd-rootless.sh. And can expose resources on the host namespace: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/38913

Comment: Can `chroot` be replaced by some namespace?

Comment: @Tim Not natively. Maybe with `pivot_root`? (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456777/7490) See also https://github.com/vincentbernat/jchroot

Comment: https://twitter.com/b0rk/status/1225445956734390273 for container illustration

Answer (score 15):

**cgroups** limits the resources which a process or set of processes can use these resources could be *CPU,Memory,Network I/O or access to filesystem* while namespace restrict the visibility of group of processes to the rest of the system.

visit for further details [How Linux Kernel Cgroups And Namespaces Made Modern Containers Possible](http://www.silicon.co.uk/software/open-source/linux-kernel-cgroups-namespaces-containers-186240?inf_by=59f18086681db813098b456c)

Answer (score 12):

**Cgroups(control groups) does resource management.**
It determines how much host machine resources to be given to containers.

for example:-
we define resources in docker-compose yaml file for creating services like:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpus: "0.1" (100 millicores)
    memory: 50M
```

Here, in this example we are explicitly asking cgroups to allocate these resources to particular container.

---

**Namespaces**: provides process isolation, complete isolation of containers, separate file system.

---

There are 6 types of namespaces:
1. mount ns - for file system.
2. UTS(Unique time sharing) ns- which checks for different   hostnames of running containers 
3. IPC ns - interprocess communication
4. Network ns- takes care of different ip allocation to different containers
5. PID ns - process id isolation
6. user ns- different username(uid)

Comment: [Wasn't  cgroup also a namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html)?